# Merge a hash inside array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to Ruby and Rails, I have stuck in a situation that I need to create an array of hashes. Please see below the code:

```
def self.v_and_c items
 result = []
 items.try(:each) do |item|
  result << item
  if item.is_parent_variation
    check_ancestor item
    result << { :item_variation => @variations }
    result << { :options => @options }
   elsif item.is_parent_customization
    check_ancestor item
    result << { :customizations => @customizations }
    result << { :ingredients => @ingredients }
   end
 end
 result
end
```

Here is the output of the function:

```
{"items":[{"id":1,"name":"Cake"},{"item_variation":null},{"options":null}]}
```

But I wanted to do like this.

```
{"items":[{"id":1,"name":"Cake","item_variation":null, "options":null} ]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
def self.v_and_c items
 result = []
 items.try(:each) do |item|
  item_hash = {}.merge(item)
  if item.is_parent_variation
    check_ancestor item
    item_hash.merge!({ item_variation: @variations }).merge!({ options: @options})
  elsif item.is_parent_customization
    check_ancestor item
    item_hash.merge!({ customizations: @customizations }).merge!({ ingredients: @ingredients})
  end
   result.push(item_hash)
 end
 result
end
```

**Explanation:**
For each iteration of loop, create an item_hash and merge all the requisite hashes in it and then push the resulting hash into the result array.

**Few pointers:**

- Take care of new Ruby hash syntax
- If check ancestor is needed in both if and else why not do it outside?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply and actually some times check_ancestor function not calling as per the condition so I called twice.

Comment: item_hash = {}.merge(item) --> this is creating error so I have changed it to item_hash = {}.merge(item: item) then it runs otherwise throw error that no implicit conversion of Item into Hash.

Comment: I assumed item to be a hash. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple like this, use .merge method

```
def self.v_and_c items
 result = []
 items.try(:each) do |item|
  result << item
  if item.is_parent_variation
    check_ancestor item
    result = result.merge { :item_variation => @variations }
    result = result.merge { :options => @options }
   elsif item.is_parent_customization
    check_ancestor item
    result = result.merge { :customizations => @customizations }
    result = result.merge { :ingredients => @ingredients }
   end
 end
 result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.v_and_c items
  [].tap do |result|
  items.try(:each) do |item|
    result_hash = item.dup
    if item.is_parent_variation
      check_ancestor item
      result_hash.merge!({ item_variation: @variations, options: @options })
    elsif item.is_parent_customization
      check_ancestor item
      result_hash.merge!({ customizations: @customizations, ingredients: @ingredients })
    end
    result << result_hash
  end
end
```

end